# Using networksetup to connect to WPA2 Enterprise with AD not authenticating

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, bash, terminal

When using networksetup to connect to a WiFi network, the WiFi symbol appears with an exclamation mark over it. It also shows that there is no 802.1x authentication in the network preferences.
I have tried the following command:

```sh
networksetup -setairportnetwork $INTERFACE "$SSID"
```

I have tried unlocking the keychain prior to setting the network and tried adding the password as the last parameter.
I have also tried setting the password in the keychain to allow all applications access to it with no restrictions.

I expect the network to be connected in the same way as when manually switching networks. However, when looking in the network preferences after connecting via networksetup, the authentication does not appear to be there.

Under network preferences, after switching manually, the status is Connected and has the message "Wi-Fi is connected to XXXX and has the IP address XXXXXXX". It also shows "802.1X: Default" and "Authenticated via EAP-PEAP (MSCHAPv2)

However, after switching with the script, the status is "On" and has the message "Wi-Fi does not have an IP address and cannot connect to the internet." There is also no message regarding 802.1X authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this using Applescript inside a bash script instead. This mimicks the way that the user would manually switch a WiFi network.

In case anyone else has this problem in the future, here's the bash function I created to do this for me.

```bsh
switchWiFi () { 
osascript \
-e'tell application "System Events"' \
    -e 'tell process "SystemUIServer"' \
        -e 'click (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 whose description contains "Wi-Fi")' \
        -e "click menu item $1 of menu 1 of result" \
    -e 'end tell' \
-e 'end tell' 
}
```

Comment: i didn't know about osascript so that's cool but i think navigating to config seems different; i got: System Events got an error: Can’t get menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 of process "SystemUIServer" whose description contains "Wi-Fi". Invalid index. (-1719)

Answer (score 0):

this solution only works if the SSID is not hidden. In my opinion, you need to fix the address and script with the networksetup command :

- if lost create a WiFi network interface
- create a new location
- join the SSID
- fix the address
- reboots the wifi power
  done that, testing time..